# How to get a list of filenames and manipulate it with gulp?

Tags: gulp

I would like to do something like this

```
  return gulp.src(['build/tags/*.tag'])
             .pipe(plugins.filelist('all.js', {
               flatten: true
             }))
             .pipe(plugins.insert.transform(function (content) {
               console.log(content);
               var list = JSON.parse(content);
               var output = "";
               list.forEach(function (file) {
                 output += "import '" + file + "'\n'";
               })
               return output;
             }))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

That is I would like to create and manipulate a list of files to output. The issue is that gulp-filelist doesn't change the stream into a list of files, it just creates a list and passed the original stream of files through.

Is there any way I can do what I'm trying to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior of `gulp-filelist` passing through the original files has [recently been changed](https://github.com/cjroth/gulp-filelist/commit/f37d480f62aeecec1411d09ea5376a49efe06739). However no new version has been pulished to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) since. That means if you run `npm install gulp-filelist` you still get the old behavior.

That leaves you with three options:

1. [Ask the developers](https://github.com/cjroth/gulp-filelist/issues) of `gulp-filelist` to publish a new version to npm so you can use the new behavior.
2. Install the current development version of `gulp-filelist` directly from github instead of using the version from npm:

   ```
   npm uninstall gulp-filelist
   npm install --save-dev cjroth/gulp-filelist
   ```
3. Use the current `gulp-filelist` version from npm, but also use [`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) to filter out all files that aren't `all.js`:

   ```
   return gulp.src(['build/tags/*.tag'])
     .pipe(plugins.filelist('all.js', {
        flatten: true
      }))
      .pipe(plugins.filter('all.js')) // only pass all.js through
      .pipe(plugins.insert.transform(function (content) {
         console.log(content);
         var list = JSON.parse(content);
         var output = "";
         list.forEach(function (file) {
           output += "import '" + file + "'\n";
         });
         return output;
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
   ```

Comment: Hi, 2 years late but letting you know that v2 is now published.